# M2Crypto.EVP.EVPError: Unable to read private key in function pkey_read_pem

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, m2crypto, wallet

I have this annoying M2Crypto error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Work/pythonWork/pkpass/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    smime.load_key(str(keypemPath), pemPath,callback=passwordCallback)   File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/M2Crypto/SMIME.py",
line 163, in load_key
    self.pkey = EVP.load_key(keyfile, callback)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/M2Crypto/EVP.py",
line 395, in load_key
    cptr = m2.pkey_read_pem(bio.bio, callback) M2Crypto.EVP.EVPError: Unable to read private key in function pkey_read_pem.`

My code:

```
def passwordCallback():
return "123456"

smime = SMIME.SMIME()
wwdrcert = X509.load_cert(wwdrpemPath)
stack = X509_Stack()
stack.push(wwdrcert)
smime.set_x509_stack(stack)
smime.load_key(str(keypemPath), pemPath,callback=passwordCallback)
```

- My Python Version is:3.6
- My openssl Version is:OpenSSL 1.0.2p
- My M2Crypto Version is:0.30.1

Comment: Something stupid like read permissions on the particular file?

Comment: @皇太极  did you solve it ???

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in M2Crypto (see https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/-/issues/260).

Please try to cast the password to a Python bytes object:

```
def passwordCallback():
    return bytes("123456", "ascii")
```